# cannot import name 'inverse_perpetual' from 'pybit'

Tags: python, import, module, bybit, python-bybit

cannot import inverse_perpetual from pybit:

```
from pybit import inverse_perpetual
```

> Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name
> 'inverse_perpetual' from 'pybit'

Comment: What version of `pybit` do you have installed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @wkl, my pybit version is 1.3.2

Comment: @wkl, thanks for the hint. I just upgraded the module and it is working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to install NumPy and pandas to resolve this issue